# dynamic update breadcrumbs with click on every horizontal panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, breadcrumbs

I am stuck into one problem last 1 day actually I want to implement horizontal Accordion with breadcrumbs on the page.how can i implement with a dynamic way like when you click on any link on horizontal Accordion at same time update breadcrumbs it something tricky part for me.do you guys have any idea?

how can i update breadcrumbs with click on every panel ?

```js
$('.items a').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      $bc = $('<div class="item"></div>');

  $this.parents('li').each(function(n, li) {
      var $a = $(li).children('a').clone();
      $bc.prepend(' / ', $a);
  });
    $('.breadcrumb').html( $bc.prepend('<a href="#Title One">test</a>') );
    return false;
})
```

```css
article.accordion
{
    display: block;
    width: 43em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #666;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
article.accordion section
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 2em;
    height: 12em;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
article.accordion section h2
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 12em;
    height: 2em;
    top: 12em;
    left: 0;
    text-indent: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ddd;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
article.accordion section h2 a
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    outline: 0 none;
}
article.accordion section:target
{
    width: 30em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
article.accordion section:target h2
{
    position: static;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-indent: 0;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
article.accordion section,
article.accordion section h2
{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmins="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
  
<body>
  
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <div class="item"><a href="#acc1">Test/ </a></div>
</div>
 <br>
<article class="accordion">
    <section id="acc1">    
       <h2><a href="#acc1"  class="items" >Title One</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on page 1.</p>       
    </section>
    <section id="acc2">
       <h2><a href="#acc2"  class="items">Title Two</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on page 2.</p>
         </div>
    </section>
    <section id="acc3">
        <h2><a href="#acc3"  class="items" >Title Three</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on page 3.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="acc4">
        <h2><a href="#acc4">Title Four</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on page 4.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="acc5">
        <h2><a href="#acc5">Title Five</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on page 5.</p>
    </section>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are tyring to call the function on `a` which are in `.items` class but no class is defined in your example.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.items').on('click', function () {

            var $this = $(this),
                $bc = $('<div class="item"></div>');
            console.log($this);
            $this.parents('li').each(function (n, li) {
                var $a = $(li).children('a').clone();
                $bc.prepend(' / ', $a);
            });
            $('.breadcrumb').html($bc.prepend('<a href="#Title One">test</a>'));
            // return false;
        })
    });
```

and in your html provide the class to `a`.

```
 <h2><a href="#acc1" class="items">Title One</a></h2>
```

Comment: Ya I know about that but it is one example i need to somthimg like this same functionality i try with li tag but its not work in section tag.